# Generation of Tomcat Stdout and Stderr log files

Tags: logging, java, tomcat7, log4j

Is there a way to catch tomcat stdout and tomcat stderr log files it to log4j or any other way so that i can keep track daily basis.These files are only generated when we restart tomcat.And i want these files to be generated automatically even without restarting a Tomcat Server.How can i achieve this. Any Suggestions.Thanks in Advance